# Is RStudio coming up with Jupyter like interface?

Tags: shiny, rstudio, r-markdown, jupyter, apache-zeppelin

I've been using Jupyterhub with R-Kernel lately and is excellent for notebook style coding but is a pain to integrate Shiny / HTML Widgets / plotly etc.. Is there a plan for RStudio to come up with a similar notebook style interface?

I understand Rmarkdown/Sweave exists but is different from Jupyter. Any Comments??

Comment: Hi from RStudio. :-) What features from Jupyter do you hope to see in RStudio? We'd welcome your input on our feature request forum: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200022758-Feature-Requests

Comment: We would like to have the ability to create and modify data on a spreadsheet way.